# How to solve this series :$\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}n-k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I tried to solve this series as follows ; $\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}n-k$ :

$
=(\frac{n}{2}+n)+(\frac{n}{2}+1+n-1)+(\frac{n}{2}+2+n-2)+...+(\frac{n}{2}+k+n-k) = \frac{n}{2}(\frac{n}{2}+n)=\frac{n^2}{4}+\frac{n^2}{2}=\frac{n^2+2n^2}{4}=\frac{3n^2}{4}
$

But I think It's open to discussion.Please guide me if it's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you try and split it into two series and try?

$S =\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}n - k \\
S =\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} n -  \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} k$

Now,one can take the $n$ out of the sum since it is independent of the sum index ($k$)

$
S =n\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} 1 -  \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}} k $

Answer (score 0):

Putting $r=n-k$ gives

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n/2} (n-k)=\sum_{r=n/2}^nr=\underbrace{\frac 12 \left(\frac n2+1\right)\left(n+\frac{n}2\right)}_{\text{using formula for sum of AP}}=\frac 38 n(n+2)\quad\blacksquare$$